# RSpec - Capybara and Puma - Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, rspec, capybara, puma

I'm trying to use Capybara as a front-end test suite (Vue) and I'm getting the following error from Puma:

```
Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/login"
```

What is the cause of this and how can I fix this? Is it something to do with the config? Let me know if I should include more code in my question.

rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require "pundit/rspec"
require "capybara/rails"
require "capybara/rspec"
require "capybara/poltergeist"
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require "paperclip/matchers"
require 'support/spec_helpers/warden_controller_helpers'
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'support/spec_helpers/webmock_helper'


Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

login_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "User login", type: :feature, js: true do

  before :each do
      @user = User.create!(
        first_name: "Bob",
        last_name: "Brown",
        email: "bob@email.com",
        password: "bob1",
        has_accepted_terms: true
      )
    end

  scenario "User logs in with correct credentials" do
    visit root_path
    save_screenshot
    click_on 'Log In'
    sleep 1
    save_screenshot

  end

end
```

Comment: Going to need more information for troubleshooting. What is creating the '/login' route? Is it devise? Can we get a look at your routes file? Does this work when you try it yourself locally, in the browser?

Comment: Add the output of running `rails routes` to your question.

Comment: I don't have a /login route in routes.rb, I'm using vue router to render the Login.vue component. Am I using the appropriate libraries to test in my situation? Everything works in the browser right now.

Comment: Are all your vue JS files transpiled and polyfilled to be <=ES5.1 compatible? If not you can't use with Poltergeist.  You're going to be much happier just using headless chrome for testing (`Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless` as a starting point until you need to customize the driver registration)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I just tried setting that up using this: https://drivy.engineering/running-capybara-headless-chrome/ I'm still getting the same error, are there any nuances that i should look out for?

Comment: If you're getting the same error, run in non-headless mode, pause the test and try interacting with it yourself (check developer console for errors, etc) - the fact you're getting an ActionController::RoutingError implies the vue router isn't doing what you think (or potentially isn't loaded at all).  As for that tutorial, it's out of date and the recommendation to use `trigger` on Poltergeist is a terrible recommendation to make without fully explaining the cost of doing that (tests are no longer doing what a user could, so what's the point of even having those tests).

Comment: @ThomasWalpole As you suggested, I do suspect it's the vue router that's not loaded which is causing my puma server to try to get /login. I tried using the non-headless mode (and used binding.pry to pause) and the only error I see is when I click "Log In" (same routing error). How can I check/ensure that vue router is working? Thanks for your help

Comment: @jj008 If there are no JS errors shown in the browsers dev console, then check the network tab to make sure it's loading everything you think it should be (the router specifically)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I can't use the vue dev tool to see if the router is loaded but the html looks the same and everything from the network looks the same. Where would the router exist within the network?

Comment: @jj008 It would be loaded in one of your JS files, which one I have no way of knowing since that's all based on how you included all your assets.  btw -  you're not using turbolinks as well as vue are you?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole turbolinks is being used (in the main.js). I inherited this project so I'm not yet familiar with every part. How would turbolinks affect capybara or puma when testing?

`$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {
  new Vue({
    el: "#app-content",
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  })
});`

Comment: @jj008 There's a possibility turbolinks may be taking over control of the link and making the request to the app - you could try disabling turbolinks on the 'Log In' link/button to see if that's the issue -- see turbolinks docs for how to do that.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I added `data-turbolinks="false"` to the `<a>` where the link to '/login' was but puma is still shooting the error :(

Comment: @jj008 Can you provide me with access to the code so I can try running the test? Or can you provide a way to replicate the issue?

Comment: @jj008 Ok -- so this doesn't work in dev environment for me (let alone test), and unless I'm missing something I don't see how it could ever work -- No JS is loaded at all for the home page.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole what's the error you're getting on the browser console? Or nothing is loaded at all?

Comment: @jj008 Explanation of your issue in the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I run the dev server and go to `'localhost:3000` (which is basically what you're telling Capybara to do) then there is a broken 'Log In' link on the page that points to `app.localhost:3000/login` which the app doesn't handle. This is because visiting a URL without the `app` subdomain uses the `application.html.haml` layout which includes no JS (and therefore no Vue router to handle the `/login` path).  If however I go to `app.localhost:3000` in the browser then there's a page with a working `Log In` link since all the JS is loaded on that page (including the Vue router) because it uses the `app.html.haml` layout (BaseController)

You need to fix the main homepage link to function correctly and/or configure Capybara to connect to the `app` subdomain by default

```
Capybara.app_host = 'http://app.localhost' # hostname with ‘app’ sub domain that resolves to interface the AUT is being run on
Capybara.always_include_port = true
```

Basically Capybaras telling you your apps main page is broken because it is broken.

Comment: I understand that I need the subdomain `app` when accessing the home page but now every page i try to render has an additional `app` in the URL (ie. app.app.localhost:62281/login), which is causing my ajax calls to break. Is it possible to get Capybara to add the `app` only on the home page?

Comment: @jj008 If the app is creating URLs like that on the page when Capybara requests it then it would be doing it for a regular user too, it really sounds like you need to figure out your routing and URL generation and fix it.  To answer your question though, if you remove the Capybara.app_host setting above you can always just call `visit('http://app.localhost/')` instead of `visit root_path` if desired, but I'm guessing you're still going to have issues later with URLs since your current url creation logic sounds broken. Maybe check `config.action_dispatch.tld_length` in the test env is correct.